# Логин ВК для WebView приложения

Tags: javascript, java, android

На моем сайте стоят виджеты ВК комментарии, но когда я логинюсь через ВК, подтверждаю кодом у меня экран становится белым и ВК не авторизовается.

[image: Комментарии]

[image: Вход через ВК]

Вот активити:

```
WebView mWebView;


@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome());
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("Ссылка на сайт");
    }

}


private class MyChrome extends WebChromeClient {

    private View mCustomView;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
    private int mOriginalOrientation;
    private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;

    MyChrome() {}

    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster()
    {
        if (mCustomView == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), 2130837573);
    }

    public void onHideCustomView()
    {
        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
        this.mCustomView = null;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
        setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
        this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
    }

    public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback)
    {
        if (this.mCustomView != null)
        {
            onHideCustomView();
            return;
        }
        this.mCustomView = paramView;
        this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Нашел выход из ситуации,как выяснилось проблема связана с блокировкой cookies в WebView, я просто добавил следующий код в метод onCreate активности:

java

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
}
```